# ogrmerge.py - How to running from Python

Tags: gdal, ogrmerge

I need merge list of shapefiles.

It is possible using `ogrmerge.py`

I use it and run using subprocess:

```py
import pathlib
import subprocess

class MergeShpFiles:
    def __init__(self, output_file: pathlib.Path):
        self.output_file = output_file

    def merge_shp_files(self, file_list: list):
        command = "ogrmerge.py -single -o "
        command += str(self.output_file) + " "
        for file in file_list:
            command += str(file) + " "
        "-src_layer_field_name country"
        subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

It is possible to run function in Python without subprocess?
It is problem when I switch between Windows and Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a worked example using Python 3 and OGR with 11 input polygon shp files named `tmp*.shp`.

```
    from osgeo import ogr
    import os
    
    outputMergefn = 'merged_features.shp'
    directory = "./"
    file_start = 'tmp'
    file_ext = '.shp'
    drvrname = 'ESRI Shapefile'
    geomtype = ogr.wkbMultiPolygon
    outputdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    
    if os.path.exists(outputMergefn):
        outputdriver.DeleteDataSource(outputMergefn)
    out_ds = outputdriver.CreateDataSource(outputMergefn) 
    out_layer = out_ds.CreateLayer(outputMergefn, geom_type = geomtype)
    
    filelist = os.listdir(directory)
    
    for file in filelist:
    if file.startswith(file_start) and file.endswith(file_ext):
         print("Processing: " + file)
         ds = ogr.Open(directory + file)
         if ds is None:
             print("ds is empty")
         lyr = ds.GetLayer()
         for feat in lyr:
             out_feat = ogr.Feature(out_layer.GetLayerDefn())
             out_feat.SetGeometry(feat.GetGeometryRef().Clone())
             out_layer.CreateFeature(out_feat)
             out_layer.SyncToDisk()
```

Comment: I try it but it not working correctly.
This is a old version Python 2 and this site is from 2013

Comment: did you have an opportunity to check if the above solution worked given that the previous link appeared to be out-dated for your set-up.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way using `osgeo_utils`, without implementing your own merge (as per @dmci's answer ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from osgeo_utils.ogrmerge import process as ogr_merge

 ogr_merge( [ "-single", "-f", "GPKG", "-o", "output.gpkg", "input*.gpkg" ] )
```

This is working here with Python3 and GDAL 3.4.3.

**Explanation**:

The source code for ogrmerge.py can be found at:
https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/ogrmerge.py

In this, you will see that the 'main' calls the `process()` function with the parsed command line parameters. So call `process()` with a list of the parameters you require.